# Make window always on top?

Tags: windows, window, window-manager

Some applications do not have the functionality like Task Manager's "Always on top" feature.

[image: task-manager-always-on-top]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I use [**Deskpins**](https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/) for this:

[image: deskpins]

There is also [**PowerMenu**](http://abstractpath.com/powermenu/) if you prefer a context menu solution, which lets you set application priority and transparency from the context menu as well:

[image: powermenu]

Comment: PowerMenu has issues with Win7/64bit go for AlwaysOnTOpMaker as suggsted below.

Comment: The adware that is installed with the link no matter whether I chose to install it or not is unbearable.

Comment: Unfortunately the latest version of Deskpins as of this writing is v1.30 and the "Alwasy On Top" functionality doesn't seem to work with Windows 8.

Answer (score 36):

Install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and use this script to toggle any window as topmost by pressing CTRL SHIFT T:

```
^+t::
      WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle,A
return
```

Comment: I prefer this way cause I can use what I create. It's quite simple too :)

Comment: Perfect match for the AutoHotkey users! Thanks :) [iglvzx's answer](http://superuser.com/a/371052/334666) has code for toggling the AlwaysOnTop to off, which is quite useful, too.

Comment: What does the `A` parameter do? I can't find it in the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm).

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit A means the current window

Answer (score 6):

[Ash's answer](https://superuser.com/a/32091/100787) using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a great alternative. However, the current state of the script can be troublesome. The `AlwaysOnTop` property is persistent even after AutoHotkey is no longer running. You could go through each window manually and **toggle** this property to `off`, but we're using AutoHotkey; We can do it *automatically*!:

```
!#Down:: ;Windows+Alt+Down
    WinGet, windows, List
    Loop, %windows%
    {
        window := windows%A_Index%
        WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_id %window%
    }
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
return
```

Answer (score 4):

The open source virtual desktop manager [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) allows you to make windows always on top (or always on another screen etc) by middle clicking on the window like so:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the application doesn't allow you to bring up this middle click menu? Like Google Chat.

Comment: @cloneman ... or Micro$oft "Sticky Notes" ... (I too am still looking for an answer to this)

Comment: you could use Autohotkey as outlined here to bind a keystroke to toggle the on top state http://superuser.com/a/32091/7018 as for Sticky Notes I prefer this app as it has a UI to let you toggle sticky notes to be on top http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) (Windows 10 & 11) has an [Always on Top utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/always-on-top) for pinning windows above other windows. The default hotkey is <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Always on Top showing Calculator window pinned]

Answer (score 0):

I've used [WindowPinner](http://www.thyante.com/index.php?id=7,0,0,1,0,0).  Small, simple, and does the job.

[image: WindowPinner]

Answer (score 0):

I will have to back up and support OnTop:

http://download.cnet.com/Planetscott/3000-2072_4-10057325.html

It has a tray icon. You can use the tray icon to enable/disable it, or "exit". Other than that I've been using it since ~2002 and like it minus the fact that it does not work with a command prompt window (per the readme, even says this). It also didn't appear to work with either calculator or notepad, or both, but that's not a big deal to me as it works with everything else I need or want it to.

Adding it to start up with the system is also not a bad idea, otherwise you'll have to remember to manually start it! Don't know if it works with Windows8 or not though.

It originally came from the site [PlanetScott](http://planetscott.ca/) but the site appears to have been replaced with a blank page.  You can still get the software from this [direct link](http://planetscott.ca/download/ontop10.zip).

Answer (score 0):

There is also amazing utility: OnTopReplica. It allows to replicate any window or its part and keep that image on top updating in real time. Which fits my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A console command with the help of freeware [Nirsoft's NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) tool -

```
nircmdc.exe win settopmost foreground 1
```

I expanded on this more in the [answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1637453/726717).