# Make a Window sticked on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make window always on top?](https://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top)

I need a solution of some software or built-in feature that allows me to stick a Window somewhere. I mean, it's any program that is not in fullscreen, and I position it in the top-left of my screen, for example, I want that when I click inside of a Window, my browser for example, it remains there.

A solid example: 
I want to let some youtube video in a small separate Window of my browser, and want to be on Facebook while I watch the video, but splitting the screen loses lot of space in my browser, so I'd prefer to let the video in the top-left screen, with the window resized, and still be able to browse without letting the video go behind my fullscreen when I click it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah you mean something like `Always on Top` option?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want some way to keep one window always on top. If so, there's a number of options:

- [Window On Top](http://www.skybn.com)
- [Actual Title Buttons](http://download.cnet.com/Actual-Title-Buttons/3000-2072_4-10107307.html)
- [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu) (works in Vista but problems have been reported in Windows 7)
- [DeskPins](http://download.cnet.com/DeskPins/3000-2072_4-52361.html) (not listed as compatible with Windows 7, but I've seen reports that it works fine)
- [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) with the following script: `^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A`
  (shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, change it to your liking)
- [Always On Top Maker](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm)