# Google Hangouts video call always on top

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to make the video of the person I'm talking to always on top of other windows. So that I could browse the web or something else while still could see him at glance.

Is this possible?

Comment: What browser and what operating system?

Comment: ubuntu lunux, chrome

Comment: **Alt+Space** brings up window menu with with 'Always on Top' and 'Minimise' and 'Maximise' and other commands. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! Do you know by any chanse how to that on windows 7 also?

Comment: See ["Make window always on top?"](http://superuser.com/q/28907/2357).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> brings up the window menu with **Always on Top**, **Minimise**, **Maximise** and other commands.

To find out how to do the same on Windows, check out the answers to ["Make window always on top?"](https://superuser.com/q/28907/2357) on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Google [picture-in-picture-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-extens/hkgfoiooedgoejojocmhlaklaeopbecg) should do the job with Chrome. Note that only after the video is started the extension will create an always on top PIP.
It does so because it seems to PIP only the media streams components like Meet videos and YouTube videos.