# How to put Google Meet and Zoom Conferences always on top?

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, zoom-meeting

When using google meet we often need to use the computer and we loose Google Meet windows or tab.
How to open a google meet meeting with the video always on top?

Answer (score 2):

Google [picture-in-picture-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-extens/hkgfoiooedgoejojocmhlaklaeopbecg) should do the job with Chrome. Note that only after the video is started the extension will create an always on top PIP.
It does so because it seems to PIP only the media streams components like Meet videos and YouTube videos.

This answer is originally addressed to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/774854/google-hangouts-video-call-always-on-top).