# Maximized and minimized windows in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm running **windows 10**. I'm for example working in word, having word maximised. Side-by-side I am supposed to calculate some values so I have opened my calculator minimised. Now, is there anyway while typing in word(maximised) I can see the calculator(minimised) in some part of my screen to jot the values?

Or to put it simply, *how can I continue working on a maximised window still be able to see a minimised window of some other program simultaneously?*

Comment: Set calculator to be "always on top" (and not minimised - if it is minimised you can't see any values ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make any windowed application 'Always On Top' without keyboard shortcut?](http://superuser.com/questions/992445/make-any-windowed-application-always-on-top-without-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: I don't find answer to my question there, sir.

Comment: There is no option as such.

Comment: And I did not just mean calculator, but for all programs on whole.

Comment: Read it again carefully. There are 3 different answers which will allow you to keep a window "always on top"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has an optional setting which allows to have change the focus without bringing the window in the foreground. As a result, you can type in one window (here: Word), while another window (or even several) are still on top of it (here: Calculator).

The setting is in 'Ease of Access'/'Keyboard'.

This is only a partly solution, as once you *click* in the window (here: Word), it does come to the top and hide all others. So you *can* move your mouse to Word, type, move your mouse to Calculator, type, move your mouse to Word, continue typing, etc.; but you cannot *click* in Word, because then the Calculator gets hidden. It is still pretty useful.

The alternative is to make one window 'Always on Top', but it also has its limitations - you need third-party software (which is often packaged with viruses or bloatware), and it is *window-specific*, so not a general solution.