# How to keep program open over fullscreen browser window?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-word, youtube

Is there a way to have another program like Word stay on top of a fullscreen browser window? For example if you were typing notes on a youtube video that was fullscreen?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/992445/make-any-windowed-application-always-on-top-without-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the wanted program to your pinned programs on the dock. Count what number it is.
2. Open your browser and set it to fullscreen.
3. Within your fullscreen browser press Windows key + number of the pinned program (ex. Windows + 3)
4. Resize the window to the wanted size, press play if using a video, press Windows + pinned program number again to bring up the program.