# Is there any way to add "always on top" option using registry, in the title bar right click menu? Without using any programs and scripts

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, window, always-on-top

As we can add any programs to our right click menu on windows by modifying the registry.
[image: example: notepad under right click menu.]

Is there any way to add an option to keep a window always on top by utilizing the title bar right click menu without using any third party software such as AHK, deskpins, etc? [image: title bar right click menu]

Comment: it's possible do make a window on top [with VBS or PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3ef9e547-adbd-48b2-a48c-44730038ee88/set-internet-explorer-always-on-top-settopmost-with-powershell?forum=ITCG,), but they can't add to the application context menu like that

Comment: What about turbo top it's not exactly what you want but maybe a good alternative [turbotop](http://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/). (Also Ubuntu has the feature you want out of the box but again not a real solution...)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Using additional software you might be able to make this work but there will still be programs that won't support it. For examples see [Make any windowed application 'Always On Top' without keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/992445/make-any-windowed-application-always-on-top-without-keyboard-shortcut).